# Alter primary key in oracle to NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Is it possible to change the primary key identity in oracle
from GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY
to  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; run

```
alter table your_table modify pk_column generated always as identity;
```

---

For example:

```
SQL> create table a1
  2    (id   number generated by default on null as identity,
  3     ime  varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> alter table a1 modify id generated always as identity;

Table altered.

SQL>
```